# line thickness of neighboring tikz rectangles rendering issues

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I would like to create multiple rectangular boxes with text in them. The boxes should be adjacent to each other and all lines should have the same thickness (I guess I could achieve the same with a table for the MWE below, however for the more complex application that I have a table would not be sufficient). I am using the `tikz` package. Here a MWE code snippet:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
            
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[
    fieldbox/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum height=1.5cm, thick, outer sep = 0pt, anchor=south west}
]
\node[fieldbox,minimum width=2.5cm] (box1) at (0,0) {Box 1};
\node[fieldbox,minimum width=2cm] (box2) at (box1.south east) {Box 2};
\node[fieldbox,minimum width=3cm] (box3) at (box2.south east) {Box 3};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

When viewing the generated pdf file with Adobe Reader it looks fine:
[image]

However when I increase the zoom level to a "page width" (which is something that many of the readers might do), the line thickness is no longer uniform and some of the lines appear to be double:
[image]

I've encountered a similar issue with tables in Latex before and I have been told that this is an issue with the renderer of the pdf viewer. Nevertheless the result is not optimal. Is there a way to make all lines have the same thickness regardless of the zoom level of the pdf viewer?

If there is no way to fix this issue, is there an alternative method to draw adjacent boxes with text in them using `tikz`?

**UPDATE:**

I also tried an alternative implementation. Unfortunately in this case some vertical lines still do appear to be thicker at certain zoom levels. This does support the response of @MDescamps above that this is a rendering issue:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(dict)[matrix of nodes,
        nodes={align=center, inner sep = 0pt},
        row 1/.style={minimum height=1.5cm, text height = 1em, text depth = 0.2em},
        column 1/.style={nodes={text width=2.5cm}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={text width=2cm}},
        column 3/.style={nodes={text width=3cm}},
    ]{
        Box 1 & Box 2 & Box 3 \\
    };
    \draw[thick, line cap=rect](dict-1-1.north west)--(dict-1-3.north east);
    \draw[thick, line cap=rect](dict-1-1.south west)--(dict-1-3.south east);
    \draw[thick](dict-1-1.north west)--(dict-1-1.south west);
    \draw[thick](dict-1-1.north east)--(dict-1-1.south east);
    \draw[thick](dict-1-2.north east)--(dict-1-2.south east);
    \draw[thick](dict-1-3.north east)--(dict-1-3.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have compiled the file and the pdf looks fine in Preview (MacOS), this is indeed a rendering issue. I've encountered similar behaviour with the TeXStudio pdf viewer.

Comment: @MDescamps Thank you very much for your reply. I agree with you that it is a rendering issue. I tried another implementation below (see the answer) and even though this time around I have a single vertical line, at certain zoom levels in Adobe Reader in Windows 10 some of the vertical lines do appear to be thicker. It is quite a bummer actually.

Comment: Your settings are absolutely right and avoid the nodes to be drawn alongside. If you encounter any issue, it's only from rendering. The render in TeXmaker is perfect at any zoom level.

Comment: @SebGlav Thank your confirmation!